# Submit ignore required form row with twig

Tags: html, twig

How adding a required form row with twig

i have used this code but not work when i submit it ignore it

```
{{ form_row(form.prenom,{'attr': {'required': 'required'} }) }}
```

**Controller**

```
  $candidat = new Candidat();
    $form = $this->createForm(CandidatType::class, $candidat);
    ;

$this->render("cvtheque/ajouter_candidat.html.twig",['form' => $form->createView()])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify it on the building of your form :

```
->add('prenom', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'customer.edit.firstname',
            'required' => true
        ])
```

Comment: but in some case i need it no required, for this raison i need to edit it in template

Comment: OK, could be the fact that you are using the form_row to set the attribute. Did you try using form_widget instead?

Comment: I have tried this but same problem, 
                    {{ form_widget(form.nom, {attr: {required: true}}) }}

Comment: Reading Symfony's doc (I assume you're using it) I found this template, you tried with quotes placed like that? 
`{{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'required': false}}) }}`
[https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-widget-form-view-variables]

Comment: Same prob with {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'required': true}}) }} ( submit ignore the attribute)

Comment: Could you update your initial question with the controller call to the form and the loaded template, please?